# Dual booting: Ubuntu 18.04 and MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 Errno 5

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

While I was installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to my MacBook Air 2017, an error occurred saying:

> The installer encountered an error copying files to a hard disk:
>   [Errno 5] Input/Output error
>   This is of the due to...

Before installation, I formatted my HDD to make sure that it will not be faulty.
Can somebody help me with that, please?